# Explain what Amazon EC2 is, and can I use it as a web hosting service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

I want to buy an Amazon EC2 instance, is it possible to use it as a web host? Like what other standard web host do. Is it recommended for web hosting? The truth is, I just want to learn this technology. So I'm thinking that I'll just host my website using Amazon EC2 to learn the cloud. And I have projects in the future and I'm planning to use Amazon EC2. But I still don't have any idea on what it is and how to use it.

Is it really cheaper than what other hosters provide?

Perhaps you can give me a starting point. Right now, I'm reading the docs in Amazon. But I think you guys can provide me with smarter answers.

Comment: I have also written [a detailed tutorial](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/09/13/running-drupal-website-amazon-ec2) about creating and configuring a Drupal-based website on the service, which I should update one of these days.

Answer (score 6):

EC2 is a cloud computing service. Essentially, you boot up an image which is activated at a node computer in the Amazon cloud.

> I want to buy an Amazon EC2 instance, is it possible to use it as a web host? Like what other standard web host do. Is it recommended for web hosting?

Yes it is possible. It could be recommended for web hosting, but I believe for small sites, it is overkill.

> Is it really cheaper than what other hosters provide?

Its on the high end with a minimum cost of $50/month. Though it is supposed to be economical on the high-end.

There are several other offerings similar to EC2. You may want to try Google AppEngine, and some others online.

Answer (score 4):

It functions like any other web host except that it is transient.  If you shut down the instance (or it crashes), your data is gone.  However, this isn't a problem if you persist data off-cloud or use one of Amazons persistence options.  Look into EC2+EBS.

You pay for what you use, so the answer to cost is that it is probably cheaper, but it depends entirely on your application.  The AWS costs are well documented.

The real advantage of cloud computing is the ability to expand and contract infrastructure based on the real-time demands of your application.  A small or very dynamic infrastructure is probably cheaper in the cloud whereas a large stable infrastructure is probably cheaper in a traditional data center.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell it is essentially like a host that provides virtual machines except it is enhanced in a few areas...

Instead of being billed per month you are billed per hour the machine is on.  This is great if you always have a small server running but turn on a secondary one if you have a traffic spike.

They also have some sort of "elastic ip" tech wherein your server appears on the same ip even though it could be running on different datacenters at different times. I imagine it like them throwing your VMWare images around the net to various datacenters as needed.

From what I can tell setting up each machine is very similar to any standard virtual server, the magic part comes by them abstracting your VM image from running on a specific host.

Also keep in mind they have more than juts EC2, couchDB for example is a document oriented DB you can access that for most peoples purposes has "unlimited scalability" but keep in mind its not the same as a relational DB.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 is designed to replace enterprise data center hardware on the cloud service model. It has scale that enables web hosting companies like GoDaddy or WPengine to host their entire business, including all of their customer sites, on the platform. The advantage comes when small businesses & start-ups are able to use the cutting edge development tools that power the largest websites at a fraction of the cost of what it would take to build the software independently. Companies that need to scale beyond one server with elastic response to web traffic in hardware provisioning are able to build apps on AWS EC2 or Kubernetes efficiently, where smaller publishers or multi-domain portfolio developers are better suited with shared hosting plans with discount rates on platform services & less requirements for systems administration.